# Нужен годный scroll spy

Tags: html, css

Нужен годный scroll spy (не бутстрап)

Comment: https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy ?

Comment: Лучше эта. (та что выше устарела и без поддержки) https://github.com/softwarespot/jquery-scrollspy